# Taking random defined Strings

Tags: java, android, methods, random

I want to do an app that, in function of the parameters checked, gives me a random String that I previusly set. The problem isn't the design of the app so the problem is the methods or classes that do what I want.

-I explain my objective with an example: 
 We have 100 plans to do this weekend. They are in a box and I want to pick randomly one. So great, I suppose that would be more or less easy, but, this weekend is raining so I want to pick a plan that it could be done even if it rains. And it's ending the month and I don't want to spend money so a free plan would be great. Then, I check the boxes "Free plan" and "Raining" and the app gives to me a random plan that meet the conditions.

How would you do that?

I was thinking about a bigs arrays like "Raining plans", "Free plans", with strings inside and when you check the two boxes the arrays were mixed and a string was randomly picked but I don't know how to do that and I think it could be done in another easiest way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A perfect use case for a database. Even with a single table.

Comment: Your array design is flawed. What if all plans are free and raining plans? Then you'll have two duplicate arrays. It would be better to have attributes in your plans and filter on these attributes, creating a list to choose a random element from. You could even circumvent the list creation if the lists are really big, but I'm guessing that's not an issue. Also, if you don't know how to manipulate arrays you might want to take a step back and go through some tutorials. Don't rush it!

Comment: @DerGolem better than arrays or whatever?

Comment: @keyser ok so with arrays it would be, but how do I give attributes to strings? Do I have to create a class for each plan and then extend that plan to the class "Rainy","Free"..?

Comment: Yes, far better! You have a tring field for plan than a series of integer fields for attributes (like Rainy, Month_End, Zero_Cost, Completed and such) - You set to 1 the attributes to indicate **true** and 0 to indicate **false**. From your UI, you set the corresponding checked values to 1 and the unchecked to 0 and you can build your select to randomize the resulting rows (and pick the top one)

Comment: @marckamoedo A class would be one way, kind of the java way. If you need a database, Der Golem is pointing you in the right direction. Having objects that corresponds to rows in a database is very common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do with a two dimentional array as follows:

```
    arr[filter][tasks];
```

let the filter values be binary strings converted to int
say you have two filters as aforementioned "rainy" and "free", the possible vaues are

```
    00 - 0(decimal value 0) - not rainy, not free
    01 - 1(decimal value 1) - not rainy, free
    10 - 2(decimal value 2) - rainy, not free
    11 - 3(decimal value 3) - rainy, free
```

when user checks both the values, then you have 1 and 1. Now convert binary 11 to integer which would be your first index.  Get the random second index for the task.
You can have any number of filters
Hint: `Integer.parseInt(binary_str, 2)` for binary to int conversion.

Comment: but I want to do it with several parameters so this way is for two parameters right?

Comment: parameter can be any number, if three possible values are (000,001,010,100...111) simply 2*n-1 possibilities.  Seems to be good when we have n a small value

Comment: @marckamoedo look at the table. think of each 0/1 as a boolean flag.